# Как использовать || (or) в v-if на vue js (nuxt js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

мне нужно создать условие, что если мы переходим на страницу '/brands' или '/brand'.

```
<div v-if="brandsOrBrand">
            //условие
        </div>
```

script

```
computed: {
         brandsOrBrand() {
             return this.$route.fullPath == '/brands' || this.$route.fullPath == '/brand';
         }
```

P.S. computed без  function()  т. к. использую nuxt js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как обычно в js , левый и правый операнд ...

```
v-if="flag && flagTwo"
v-if="flag || flagTwo"
```

[JSFIDD пример](https://jsfiddle.net/28Lvfkv2/1/)

Comment: К сожалению в vue js так не работает

Comment: @Jussia Предоставте больше данных тогда , тк все работает , добавил ссылку к ответу

Comment: Условие должно быть таким 

`<div v-if="$route.fullPath == '/brands' || $route.fullPath == '/brand'">
            <AlphabetSearch/>
        </div>`

Comment: Посмотрите что вы получаете во $route.fullPath и как вы сравниваете , я незнаю что там вам приходит , вопрос заключался в операторе и\или , они работает , возможно у вас условия не правельные

Comment: $route.fullPath приходит полная ссылка, тут все точно работает. Когда я записываю условие

Comment: сделайте небольшой пример на JSfidd ... ,  а то так не угадаешь в чем проблема

Comment: $route.fullPath приходит полная ссылка, тут все точно работает. Когда я записываю условие `<div v-if="$route.fullPath == '/brands' || $route.fullPath == '/brand'"> <AlphabetSearch/> </div>`, то выполняется только для '/brands'. Т. е. ошибки никакой не выскакивает, просто условие не срабатывает.

Comment: Что значит выполняеться ? если там true , то оно даже не будет высчитывать правый операнд , так как стоит оператор ИЛИ(||)

Comment: Точно)) А как мне построить условие, чтобы мое условие выполнялось и для перого и для второго? Т. е. Условие должно быть примерно таким: если ты переходить по любой из ссылок '/brands'  или '/brand' -  условие выполняется.

Comment: так с ИЛИ(||)  если любой из них будет true , то будет выполняться .То есть щас оно так и работает )